# How to highlight a item of ListView on DragOver Event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have the follow situation:

In my Windows Forms application, I have two ListView Controls and I need to drag and drop a item from ListView1 to ListView2.
When I select the item on ListView1 and drag over the item of ListView2, I want highlight the item that I put the mouse over in ListView2, to indicate what item of ListView2 receives the drop.

Below, my actual code on `ListView2.DragOver` Event:

```
private void listView2_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point pto = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;            
    Point localpoint = listView2.PointToClient(pto);
    ListViewItem item = listView2.GetItemAt(localpoint.X, localpoint.Y);
    listView2.Items[item.Index].Focused = true;
    listView2.Items[item.Index].Selected = true;
}
```

There are two problems with this code:

a) The `GetItemAt()` method doesn't return a valid item (returns null). I already tried to change the source of coordinates to `Cursor.Position`, but it's not works too. How could I catch the item by mouse location in this event?

b) Even I change the index of the Item in `listView2.Items[item.Index]`, nothing comes highlighted or selected on `listview2`.
What I should use to highlight or select the item when drag over its?

If you could help me, I would appreciate very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably simpler to use the [ListView.HitTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.hittest) Method:

> *Provides item information, given an x- and y-coordinate*.

You also need to check whether:

- the Item at that coordinates is not null (there isn't an Item under the Cursor position).
- the Item is already Selected. If it is, don't set it again, since it would cause flickering.

```
private void listView2_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    var item = listView2.HitTest(listView2.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))).Item;
    if (item != null && (!item.Selected)) item.Selected = true;
}
```

► The `ListView.View` mode is not specified. If you have `.View = View.Details;`, you probably prefer to set **`FullRowSelect = true`**: the DragOver *effect* is quite better.

Comment: Thanks Jimi. I try to do what you show, but doesn't work. Yes, I have one item in listview2, but when I check de coordinates that DragEventsArgs in DragOver event returns, it's diferent of the coordinates that MouseDown event retuns in the same place, for example.

Comment: This code is used to highlight the Item where the Mouse is dragged over. You need to have more than one item to see it working. The MouseDown event is not needed. When the DragDrop operation is completed, because the mouse button is released, the Item where the drop occurred is already the selected Item, since this code performs the selection already. Try to drag over your ListView a file from Explorer.